# dock disappears, I have auto-hide off on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dock

[image: dock gone]

So I have invalidate caches on Android Studio which closes that and then the dock reappears.

I tried a solution on another question but that did not work.

What else can I try?

Comment: Please state what you tried. Thanks.